# Vuetify grid - reverse order of columns on screen-size break

Tags: css, vuetify.js

I have a row of 2 columns that I want to display in their current order. However, when the screen sized is reduced I want to change the order of the columns so column two becomes the first column.

```html
<v-row>
    <v-col cols='12' sm='12' md='12' lg='6'>Description</v-col>
    <v-col cols='12' sm='12' md='12' lg='6'><v-img :src="..."/></v-col>
</v-row>
```

When viewed on a smaller screen or the browser is scaled down, the columns will stack and I want the second column to move to the top.

```
Full Width
______________________
|          |         |
|   Col1   |   Col2  |
|__________|_________|

Screen Break
____________
|          | 
|   Col2   | 
|__________|
|          | 
|   Col1   | 
|__________|
```

Currently col1 is on top.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use [vuetify's responsive flex order classes](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/flex/#flex-order) to achieve this effect.

for example you can put `class="order-last order-md-first"` on `Col1` in your example, this will cause the first `v-col` to render in the last flex position up until `md` breakpoint from which it will render in the first flex position.

run the example below and hit 'Full Page' to see the effect in action.

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.config.devtools = false;

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
});
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-container>
      <v-row class="pa-5">
        <v-col cols="12" md="6" class="order-last order-md-first">Title one</v-col>
        <v-col cols="12" md="6">Title two</v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```